# Store Meteor.setTimeout return value in Collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, timeout

I want to store the `handle` giving by `Meteor.setTimeout()` into my own Timers Collection. The problem is i get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error doing this...

Client side I get an `int ID` but server side I get a object like this that my `update` function doesn't want to store...

```
{ _idleTimeout: 10000,
  _idlePrev: 
  { _idleNext: [Circular],
    _idlePrev: [Circular],
    msecs: 10000,
    ontimeout: [Function: listOnTimeout] },
 _idleNext: 
  { _idleNext: [Circular],
    _idlePrev: [Circular],
    msecs: 10000,
    ontimeout: [Function: listOnTimeout] },
 _idleStart: 1421848999217,
 _monotonicStartTime: 4341630336,
 _onTimeout: [Function],
 _repeat: false }
```

Look at my code (only server side), here is timer creation:

```
triStartTimer: function (timerId, timerDuration)
{   
    var meteorTimer = Meteor.setTimeout(function()  {timerCallbackTimeout(timerId);}, timerDuration);
    console.log(meteorTimer);
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    var data = {
        duration : timerDuration,
        timerID : meteorTimer,
        start : start,
        state : timerStateEnum.RUNNING
    };

    var ret = updateTimerInfos(timerId, data);
    return ret;
},
```

The update function that get the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` :

```
var updateTimerInfos = function (id, data)
{
  var ret = Timers.update(id,
  {
    $set :
    {
        duration : data.duration,
        timerID : data.timerID,   // Without this, the function works fine
        start : data.start,
        state : data.state
    }
  }, function (error, result)
  {
    if (error)
    {
        console.log("updateTimer FAILED !!!");
        console.log("reason : " + error.message);
    }
  } );
  return ret;
}
```

Anyway, the Timeout work fine. The callback is called with the right value. But I need the `ID` to disarmed the Timeout in certain conditions...

If you have an idea or the solution, feel free =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a shortcoming of `setTimeout`, which should only ever be used on a sessional basis for exactly this reason.  You can't store the handle in your DB as it's not an [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ejson)-compatible value, and I'm unaware of any way to pick out an individual EJSON-compatible sub-object which can then be used to retrieve (and stop) the timeout in question (although I stand to be corrected).

The solution is to use a package for scheduling if your requirement is anything other than very simple.  Have a look at [percolate:synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron), which I used for [this tutorial](http://richsilv.github.io/meteor/scheduling-events-in-the-future-with-meteor/).

Comment: Thank you for your response and for your reactivity. It's weird that the return value is so different Server side and Client side . Anyway, I will look about the package you advised me.

Comment: yes - it's a function of how different Node and browser JS implementations actually are, which Meteor does a very good job of papering over.